# Whats wrong with the image scaling in igraph?

Tags: python, plot, resolution, igraph

I have a problem in controlling the size of objects in network plots done by igraph. The documentation of the `plot` command says:

- **bbox:**: The bounding box of the plot. This must be a tuple containing the desired width and height of the plot. The default plot is 600 pixels wide and 600 pixels high.
- **arrow_size:** Size (length) of the arrowhead on the edge if the graph is directed, relative to 15 pixels.
- **vertex_size:** Size of the vertex in pixels

So to my understanding all these arguments represent numbers of pixels. 
Therefore, multiplying all of them, say, by a factor of `2`, I would expect the images to scale completely with this factor.

Consider this following minimal example in python:

```
from igraph import Graph, plot

def visualize(res=1.0):

    g=Graph([(0,1), (1,0)], directed=True)

    layout = g.layout_fruchterman_reingold()

    plot(g, target='plot.png', 
         layout=layout,
         bbox=(120*res,120*res),  
         vertex_size=5*res, 
         arrow_size=10*res)
```

This plots a trivial graph,
However for `res=1.0` and `res=2.0` the arrows and vertices become smaller compared to the image size.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but could the stroke width account for the difference? The default stroke width is 1 units, and you don't seem to scale the stroke width. Try setting `vertex_frame_width=res` in the call to `plot()`.